# Send Email via Apex

Tags: apex, visualforce, email-template

I have a bit of a unique situation.  Currently, I have an email template set up that uses a Visualforce page as the template.  The VF page is necessary because the template loops through Cases related to an Account that match a particular criteria.  I then have an Email Alert WFR set up to fire when a date is reached.  The WFR fires on the Account, and I have mutliple lookup fields on the Account to Contacts that match a particular type.  All this works fine, however, there is no tracking of the email via the Email Alert, so any email responses have to be linked back into SFDC manually.

My question is whether or not I can accomplish this same process using Apex code rather than a WFR Email Alert, and if using the code would then allow me to track responses for each Case listed in the email template, using something like the `ref: {!Case.Id}` code?  My template is below:

***Email Template:***

```
<messaging:emailTemplate recipientType="Contact"
  relatedToType="Account"
  subject="Notification - {!relatedTo.Name} - {!TODAY()}"
  replyTo="test@test.com">
  <messaging:htmlEmailBody >
    <html>
      <body>
        <STYLE type="text/css">
          TH {font-size: 11px; font-face: arial;background: #CCCCCC;
               border-width: 1;  text-align: center } 
          TD  {font-size: 11px; font-face: verdana } 
          TABLE {border: solid #CCCCCC; border-width: 1}
          TR {border: solid #CCCCCC; border-width: 1}
        </STYLE>
        <font face="arial" size="2">
          <p>Hi {!relatedTo.Contact_4__r.Name},</p>
          <p>We would like to inform you of the following issue(s) found on {!relatedTo.Name} and would appreciate your immediate attention to this matter.<br/></p>
          <table border="0" columns="2">
            <apex:variable value="{!1}" var="ViolationNum"/>
            <apex:repeat var="cx" value="{!relatedTo.Cases}">
            <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!IF(cx.Escalate_to_Client__c = TRUE && relatedTo.Client_Escalate_Date__c = cx.Client_Escalated__c,TRUE,FALSE)}">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><b><u>Violation #<apex:outputText value="{!FLOOR(ViolationNum)}"/></u></b></td>
                    <apex:variable var="ViolationNum" value="{!ViolationNum + 1}"/>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="17%">Case Number:</td>
                    <td width="83%">{!cx.CaseNumber}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="17%">Violation Type:</td>
                    <td width="83%">{!cx.Type_of_Violation__c}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="17%">Description of Violation:</td>
                    <td width="83%">{!cx.Compliance_Violation_Description__c}</td>
                </tr>
                <br/><br/>
            </apex:outputPanel>
            </apex:repeat>
            </Table>

            Please respond to this email by 
                <b><apex:outputText value="{0, date, MMMM d','  yyyy}">
                    <apex:param value="{!CASE( MOD( TODAY() - DATE(1900, 1, 7), 7),0, TODAY() + 2,1, TODAY() + 2,2, TODAY() + 2,3, TODAY() + 2,4, TODAY() + 4,5, TODAY() + 4,6, TODAY() + 3,null)}"/>
                </apex:outputText></b>
            indicating whether the above has been resolved so that we may review and confirm complete resolution.<p/>

            Thank you for your prompt attention to this matter!<p/>

        </font>
      </body>
    </html>
  </messaging:htmlEmailBody> 
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Comment: I guess you can use apex to do this. `setSaveAsActivity(saveAsActivity)` method of class `Email` allows you to save the email as activity. More info here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_base.htm

Comment: if you want to track email responses - consider inbound apex email handler

Comment: @cropredy - Is that an app or some Apex code?

Comment: Apex Inbound Email Handler is code; [See doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_inbound_what_is.htm). You could parse out the `ref: {someId}`